# How to create a table with two columns, the first one's width is Auto and the second one is 100%

Tags: html, html-table

In a table:

How to set width for columns to implement the following:

Two columns, the width of the first one is fit the maximum width of content. and the width of the second one is the rest of the table's width.

Comment: If the first one is the maximum width of the content how can the second one still have a width?

Comment: From what I understand I think you'll want to look into colspan?

Comment: @Mythje: I'll set maximum width

Comment: @Andre Backlund: I've tried to set an image to clarify it, but I couldn't because I don't have the enough reputation :(

Comment: Can you upload it somewhere else and link to it maybe?

Comment: What is the content of the first column? Text or images? And of the second column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
    table, 
    td.col2 {width:100%}
    td.col1 {white-space:nowrap;}
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">Column 1 content here</td>
        <td class="col2">Column 2 content here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```